# SharePoint Online REST API: enable role inheritance only at one level

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I try to enable role inheritance on the item which has unique role permissions. I found that it does call `ResetRoleInheritance`. Unfortunately according to the documentation it resets role inheritance on all levels under the item for which that call is performed.

Is it possible to reset role inheritance only for the one item with preserving inheritance settings (enabled or disabled) on the underlying levels?

Answer (score 1):

Reset permission for item level.

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TestList')/items('5')/resetroleinheritance
```

Comment: Can you give me please a link for the documentation, where it's written that /resetroleinheritance resets only for an item level? Thank you.

Comment: By the way - is it possbile to disable role definition ineheritance on SharePoint Online and create role definition not only on site collection level?